# Python: Extract XML texts except under certain tags

Tags: python, xml

I have this example XML file:

```
<page>
  <title>Chapter 1</title>
  <content>Welcome to Chapter 1</content>
  <author>John Smith</author>
</page>
<page>
 <title>Chapter 2</title>
 <content>Welcome to Chapter 2</content>
 <author>John Doe</author>
</page>
```

This XML may have multiple levels (i.e. more than 2) and may have other tags. I wish to extract all texts except those under the tag "content", so that I get a list of strings as follows:

```
['Chapter 1', 'John Smith', 'Chapter 2', 'John Doe']
```

I'm implementing this task using ElementTree. Is there any elegant, clean solution?

Comment: _"I'm implementing this task using ElementTree"_ -- probably a good place to start.  _"Is there any elegant, clean solution"_ -- quite likely, but we don't write solutions for you. Show what you have done so far.  Visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: What I have right now is to use xpath, i.e. something similar to xpath('*/text()'). However, I want something like a blacklist to filter out texts under unwanted tags. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

```
import bs4

xml = '''<page>
  <title>Chapter 1</title>
  <content>Welcome to Chapter 1</content>
  <author>John Smith</author>
</page>
<page>
 <title>Chapter 2</title>
 <content>Welcome to Chapter 2</content>
 <author>John Doe</author>
</page>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')
[(page.title.text, page.author.text)for page in soup('page')]
```

out:

```
[('Chapter 1', 'John Smith'), ('Chapter 2', 'John Doe')]
```

Use BeautifulSoup as XML parser, you can reference [Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)